# Postgres query fails in sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

From my nodejs application I run this line:

```
return models.sequelize.query("INSERT INTO \"DelegateUserLinks\" VALUES 
(" + id + "," + _user.id + ", '2019-01-10 13:06:41.920', '2019-01-10 
13:06:41.920')", function(err){
            return Promise.reject(err);
        });
```

This fails. I dont really understand why. Reading the error log the error has the code `22P02`.
What I understand, the error code means there is a failure when converting a datatype to integer.
But I cannot see Im having this issue (looking at the query). The query itself (printed in the error log) seems allright in my eyes:

```
INSERT INTO \"DelegateUserLinks\" VALUES (10,677, '2019-01-10 13:06:41.920', '2019-01-10 13:06:41.920')"
```

If the issue is casting from datatype to integer, I see that the number  `10` and `677` are written in the query as pure integers. So what is the real problem? Im also hard coding the dates to be sure the problem is not there. This is the full error log:

```
{"name":"SequelizeDatabaseError","parent":{"name":"error","length":117,"severity":"ERROR","code":"22P02","position":"49","file":"numutils.c","line":"104","routine":"pg_atoi","sql":"INSERT INTO \"DelegateUserLinks\" VALUES (10,677, '2019-01-10 13:06:41.920', '2019-01-10 13:06:41.920')"},"original":{"name":"error","length":117,"severity":"ERROR","code":"22P02","position":"49","file":"numutils.c","line":"104","routine":"pg_atoi","sql":"INSERT INTO \"DelegateUserLinks\" VALUES (10,677, '2019-01-10 13:06:41.920', '2019-01-10 13:06:41.920')"},"sql":"INSERT INTO \"DelegateUserLinks\" VALUES (10,677, '2019-01-10 13:06:41.920', '2019-01-10 13:06:41.920')","error@context":{}}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the **complete** error message you get.

Comment: I already added the complete error message?

Comment: Can you share your table's schema? Does it have 4 columns and are those 4 columns `int`, `int`, `timestamp`, `timestamp`? Also you may want to consider using sequelizes bind parameter logic to avoid sql injection attacks, or at the very least use sequelize replacement so your literals are escaped.

Comment: Ahhhhh....it has 5 fields. Actually it also has the id at the beginning. It could be the real issue. Not really sure how to specify the ID (should be incrementable). Need to google if nobody can give a tip here..

Comment: I can only see an error code, but no error message

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with the example in the question - you are not using Sequelize as an ORM properly. Inserts should be handled by `Model.create()` and you should sanitize the values with Sequelize rather than creating a raw insert statement.

Comment: You'll need to specify the columns to which you are inserting like `INSERT INTO yourtable (somecol, somecol2, someothercol, somothercol4) VALUES (...` leaving your `id` column out of that list so that your default/autoincrement is used during the insert. That being said, I would highly suggest following @doublesharp suggestion to NOT craft your own insert statement but rather use the ORM properly with the `Model.create()` and at the very least use replacement or parameter binding as I mentioned above.